# Creating a Barchart in Google map API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to create a simple Bargraph using Google Map API. The Source Code is given as below. I'm sure data.php is working well. 
The Graph is displayed for the first input parameters. but as I click the button there is no any output. How can I solve the problem ?

```
<html>
  <body id="body">
    <div id="content">
      <form action ="" method ="POST">
        <tr id="tableRow">
          <th valign="bottom">Select country:</th>
          <td>
            <select name="country" id="myCountry" class="">
              <option value = "AFG">Afganistan</option>
              <option value = "ARE">UAE</option>
              <option value = "GBR">United Kingdom</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <th valign="bottom">Select parameters:</th>
          <td>
            <select name="indices" id="myIndices" class="">
              <option value= "foodfinal">Vulnerability on food</option>
              <option value= "waterfinal">Vulnerability on water </option>
              <option value= "ecosystemfinal">Vulnerability on ecosystem </option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td valign="top">
            <input type="button" class="action" onclick="displayGraph();" value="Display Graph"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      displayGraph();

      function displayGraph(){
        var country = document.getElementById('myCountry').value;
        var index = document.getElementById('myIndices').value;
        alert(index);

        var content = document.getElementById("content");
        document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("body").appendChild(content);

        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
          var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "data.php?&country="+country+"&indices="+index,
            dataType:"json", 
            async: false, 
            success : function(data) {
              alert(data); 
            }
          }).responseText;

          // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, {width: 1500, height: 700});
        }
      }
    </script>
    <body>
      <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
      <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </body>
    <!--Load the AJAX API--> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML layout seems a bit messy with two `body` elements nested inside each other.

Answer (score 1):

When you hit the button, the `displayGraph` function gets executed the second time. Hence, I would expect the command

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
```

to do nothing because the package was already loaded. As a result the callback you define with

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

will not get executed again because the package is not loaded again.

To resolve this you could use something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(displayGraph);

  function displayGraph(){
    var country = document.getElementById('myCountry').value;
    var index = document.getElementById('myIndices').value;
    alert(index);

    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("body").appendChild(content);

    // These two lines are not needed anymore
    //google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
    //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "data.php?&country="+country+"&indices="+index,
        dataType:"json", 
        async: false, 
        success : function(data) {
          alert(data); 
        }
      }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 1500, height: 700});
    }

    // Since we removed the on-load callback we need to call drawChart manually
    drawChart();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you mean , Keeping the lines google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    google.setOnLoadCallback(displayGraph); above and starting the Function displaygraph Just after that ?

Comment: Yes, and then in `displayGraph` you need to call `drawChart` manually.

Comment: Well, you just do a `drawChart();`. The function was called as the on-load-callback before so now you need to call it yourself.

Comment: Is it still the same behavior that the chart is displayed on page load but nothing happens when you click the button?

Comment: @ Hennes. SO, I have to include drawChart() inside the function displayGraph ? Right ?

Comment: @ Hennes. This time the chart is not even displayed on the page load and nothing happens when I click the button. I could have made a mess out of it. My New code is like this : http://pastebin.com/rAs6nYR0

Comment: @CivaBhusal Yes, please see my revised answer. I included the changed code.

Comment: @CivaBhusal In your PasteBin code you also need to remove the statement `displayGraph();` before `function displayGraph(){`. In addition the line `drawChart();` needs to be moved to the very end of the function `displayGraph`. Again, please see my revised answer.

Comment: @ Hennes, I saw your revised answer. It returned right data but the Graph is not displayed.

Comment: @CivaBhusal What do you mean by "it returned right data"? Do you mean the AJAX call retrieves the data on button-click but the chart does not render?

Comment: yes, The AJAX call retrieves the data on button click but the chart is not rendered.

Comment: I used this function to alert the data . alert(JSON.stringify(data)); It returned the right JSON object but still there is no graph rendered. Thank you for all your time and help.

Comment: @CivaBhusal Hmm, that's very strange. Could you run your website in Chrome and check the JavaScript console (appears on F12) for any error output?

Comment: @ Hennes, The Output is correct but it has not been rendered in the Graph.

Comment: @ Hennes, I Looked at the Console on the Chrome. It says : Container is not defined.

Comment: @CivaBhusal What container? Could you check which line in the code the error refers to?

Comment: It says : Line No 35.

Comment: @CivaBhusal Could you paste the line itself, cause I'm not sure what your source looks like now.

Comment: @ Hennes, Line No 38 is this one :  <script type="text/javascript" src="include/jsapi"></script>

Comment: @CivaBhusal You said line number 35 before but now it seems to be 38. If the error is on that line, then the error is in that file (`include/jsapi`). Note, that you can navigate to the source code directly from the JavaScript console in Chrome (the links are on the right-hand side).